# new a file in coco2d-x project with xcode

Tags: cocos2d-x

when i create a cocos2d-x project, the window like this: 
[image]

when i new a file,the window like this:

[image]

how can i new a file that inheritance CCLayerColor?

Comment: by changing the super class in the header after creating the class

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in Xcode but in Visual Studios under `Right Click->Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories` There are Cocos 2dx Files are included where one of the files contains `CCLayerColor`.If you want to find it in Cocos 2d-x folder go to `<Cocos 2d-x Home Folder>cocos2dx\layers_scenes_transitions_nodes\CCLayer.h` You can find it there.